# React Router: Component is not rendering but the URL is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This kind of "*component not rendering in React Router*" type of questions seem to be a very frequently asked question. I have looked through everything but I could not find a solution for my problem.

Here is how my code look like:

```
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <SearchBar searchBody={this.state.body}/>
            <Route path = "/ranked/" component ={Ranked}></Route>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Above, the component **Ranked** is created which, depending on the subpath renders different things. 
(For example, **localhost:3000/ranked/NBA**)

```
function SearchDropDown(props){

    return(

        <div className = "searchDropDownItem">
                <Link to={"/ranked/"+props.item.url}>{props.item.name}</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Above is a different component with the **Link** tag, which, depending on the url, links to different subpath of **/ranked/**.

The problem is that let say I am on **localhost:3000/ranked/NBA**.

If I get redirected to **localhost:3000/ranked/WNBA** through the linked tag, the url is updated correctly but the component is refreshed to itself.

**From the solutions from previous related posts, I have tried**

`<Route exact path = "/ranked" ...`

**But it didn't work.**

What could be the problem here? How do I solve it?

Comment: I think it is because you wrote your Route component in a `<Route></Route>` way. In this case, React tries to render what is between the 2 tags. Try either to use a single tag `<Route />`, or to write the following code: `<Route><Ranked></Route>`

Comment: I just tried it and it doesnt seem to work. I also tried using <Route /> for the exact path and it still didnt work.

Comment: I think you are misusing the Router. Try to look at the examples here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start . Your `Route` elements should be inside a `BrowserRouter` element in order to work

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend your route look something like this instead `/route/:org` if you expect to receive props at the end of that specified route.  Then inside your `Ranked` component you would use `this.props.match.params.org` to get the organization you want ie. (NBA, WNBA).  After you have received these props in your `Ranked` component then you can render what ever you need for that specified organization.  Hopefully this makes some sense.